# Using "RecursiveArrayIterator class" for count items in complex array recursive

Tags: php, laravel, multi-level

I need to count how many users there are in this array, also have a total of users above or below the array using PHP RecursiveArrayIterator library.

How to make this count?

What I currently have to set up the network (object convert in array):

```
Array
(
    [left] => 
    [center] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
            [name] => Leo Turner
            [username] => ayla.zemlak
            [email] => gottlieb.geovany@example.net
            [sponsor] => 1
            [indicate] => 1
            [network] => Array
                (
                    [left] => 
                    [center] => Array
                        (
                            [user_id] => 8
                            [name] => Jaiden Simonis
                            [username] => cgorczany
                            [email] => genoveva31@example.net
                            [sponsor] => 1
                            [indicate] => 
                            [network] => Array
                                (
                                    [left] => 
                                    [center] => 
                                    [right] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [right] => 
                )

        )

    [right] => 
)
```

My Tree class for the new solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Tree
{
    public $total;
    public $hasUp;
    public $hasDown;
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $username;
    public $treeDefault;
    public $network;

    public function __construct( $id )
    {
        $this->total = 'total users';
        $this->hasUp = 'get user up in array';
        $this->hasDown = 'get user down in array';
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $this->getUser('name');
        $this->email = $this->getUser('email');
        $this->username = $this->getUser('username');
        $this->treeDefault = $this->getTreeJson( $id );
        $this->network = $this->getNetwork( $id );
    }

    /**
     * @param $field
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser( $field )
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::where( 'id', $this->id )->first();
        return $user[ $field ];
    }

    /**
     * @param null $id
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTreeJson( $id = null )
    {
        return json_encode( $this->getNetwork( $id ) );
    }

    /**
     * Mount Tree Array
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNetwork( $id = null )
    {
        $hasId = (isset($id) ? $id : $this->id);
        $network = \App\Models\Network::where( 'user_id', $hasId )->first();
        $tree = json_decode( $network['users'] );
        foreach( $tree as $key => $item ) {
            $newTree[ $key ] = ($item->user != '' ? new Tree( $item->user ) : null);
        }
        return (isset($newTree) ? $newTree : null);
    }
}
```

(Complex for me, I have little experience)

Thanks

Comment: What array are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to show the array speaking, I edited the question. Grateful.

Comment: Please paste your codes here.

Comment: Update with code inline

Comment: @Raank Please check my answer below. Do you think my answer can be any hint to your problem. If there is anything that you find confusing just let us know and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution however without RecursiveArrayIterator:

```
function calc_users($array) {
    static $count = 0;

    if (isset($array['center']['network'])) {
        calc_users($array['center']['network']);
    }

    if (isset($array['left']['network'])) {
        calc_users($array['left']['network']);
    }

    if (isset($array['right']['network'])) {
        calc_users($array['right']['network']);
    }

    if (isset($array['left']['user_id'])) {
        $count++;
    }
    if (isset($array['right']['user_id'])) {
        $count++;
    }
    if (isset($array['center']['user_id'])) {
        $count++;
    }

    return $count;
}

$arr = [
    'left' =>null,
    'center' => [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'network' => [
            'left' =>null,
            'center' => [
                'user_id' => 1,
                'network' => [
                    'left' =>null,
                    'center' =>null,
                    'right' =>null,
                ]
            ],
            'right' => null
        ],
    ],
    'right' => ['user_id' => 10, 'network' => []]
];

print_r(calc_users($arr));// print 3
```

Comment: It's a good idea to count the total number of users on the network. It helps your idea. I had a very heavy way, this idea quite relieved requests. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using `RecursiveArrayIterator` in combination with `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

```
<?php

$networks = [
    'left' => [
            'user_id' => 5,
            'name' => 'User1',
            'username' => 'ayla.zemlak',
            'email' => 'gottlieb.geovany@example.net',
            'sponsor' => 1,
            'indicate' => 1,
            'network' => [
                'left' => '',
                'center' => [
                        'user_id' => 8,
                        'name' => 'User2',
                        'username' => 'cgorczany',
                        'email' => 'genoveva31@example.net',
                        'sponsor' => 1,
                        'indicate' => '',
                        'network' => [
                            'left' => '',
                            'center' => '',
                            'right' => '',
                        ]
                    ],
                'right' => '',
            ]
        ],
    'center' => [
            'user_id' => 5,
            'name' => 'User3',
            'username' => 'ayla.zemlak',
            'email' => 'gottlieb.geovany@example.net',
            'sponsor' => 1,
            'indicate' => 1,
            'network' => [
                'left' => '',
                'center' => [
                        'user_id' => 8,
                        'name' => 'User4',
                        'username' => 'cgorczany',
                        'email' => 'genoveva31@example.net',
                        'sponsor' => 1,
                        'indicate' => '',
                        'network' => [
                            'left' => '',
                            'center' => '',
                            'right' => '',
                        ]
                    ],
                'right' => '',
            ]
        ],
    'right' => [
        'user_id' => 8,
        'name' => 'User5',
        'username' => 'cgorczany',
        'email' => 'genoveva31@example.net',
        'sponsor' => 1,
        'indicate' => '',
        'network' => [
            'left' => '',
            'center' => '',
            'right' => '',
        ]
    ],
];

$arrayIterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($networks);
$usersIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $arrayIterator,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($usersIterator as $key => $user) {
    if (in_array($key, ['left', 'center', 'right']) && is_array($user)) {
        echo $user['name'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output would be :

```
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
```

Here the trick is to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` in second argument of `RecursiveIteratorIterator` which otherwise will be skipped during iteration. Please refer to [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) to have more insights.

In above snippet you have to tweak the code in between `foreach` block to suit your need. Hope this gives you some idea.

Let us know if you have any confusions, queries.

Comment: His idea is also valid, I searched some solutions to what I need based on your answer, thank you.

Comment: If you think my answer helped you to find the solution then please do not forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOR USERS ON UP in array:
(father relation)

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getHasUp()
{
    /*
     * Search current user father
     * Primary find
     */
    $qualify = Network::findQualify( $this->id );

    /*
     * Set the first list item with a first qualified father
     */
    $list[1] = $qualify;

    /*
     * Mount a list with first father
     */
    for( $i = 2; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
        if ( isset($list[$i - 1]) ) {
            /*
             * Searches the father of item previous
             */
            $list[$i] = Network::findQualify( $list[$i - 1] );
        }
    }

    /*
     * Removes items with value null
     */
    return array_filter($list);
}
```

Thank you all for your help